# Problem with batch processing of images

Tags: image-processing, procedural-programming, microscopy

I am having some problems with a palette I have designed to apply identical image processing to microscopy images. I would like to apply identical processing across a folder of images (representing the results of one experiment). At present, I have a Palette that allows the user to adjust various filters via slider to identify features in one single image. It then extracts data for each feature and exports that to a table. However, I have a large number of images in different folders for several experiments and would like to batch process each folder using the settings from one representative image.

I have imported one folder of images as named variables using:

```
Import[SystemDialogInput["Directory"]]; 
images = FileNames["*.jpg"]; 
count = 1 
x = Do[imagevar[count++] = Import[image], {image, images}]
```

This allows me to do image processing by calling the individual images as imagevar[1], imagevar[2] etc. and applying filtering to each, but I need to be able to batch process all the images in a folder without knowing how many there are (there are a lot of images, and the number varies between folders) or adding additional code as I would like this tool to be used by other people with no programming knowledge.

I have taken this approach as I need to be able to process the images, and then use ImageSubtract on the filtered images and their originals e.g.

```
ImageSubtract[imagevar[1], processed[1]]
```

I have tried using:

```
subtracted[original_, filtered_] := ImageSubtract[original, filtered]

subtracted[imagevar[i], processed[i]]
```

but this does not seem to work.

I can apply filters to all the images at once in a table, but ImageSubtract does not work, so I need to be able to call on each image individually within the code.

Is there a way to either import the images as individual variables, and then apply the filtering and image subtraction to each in a loop, or filter and subtract images as a table? Thank you!

Comment: What problem are you encountering with ImageSubtract? Is there an error message?

Comment: This is really strange: `count = 1 
x = Do[imagevar[count++] = Import[image], {image, images}]`. You can just do `myimages = Import /@ images` , then `Map[ImageSubtract[#,filtering[#]]&, myimages]` I am assuming you have some function like `filtering[img_]` that works and produces an  image of the same dimensions as the original?

Comment: In addition to what flinty says: Beware that you load all images in the folder to RAM at the same time. So if you do not have many images and not so much memory available, you might be better off with something like `Block[{img},
 Do[
  img = Import[file];
  Export[
   newfilename[file],
   ImageSubtract[img, filtering[img]]
   ];
  , {file, images}]
 ]`. Here, `newfilename` is a function that creates the file name for the modified file from the file name of the original file.

Comment: @flinty Thank you for the help- that works great! As for the other bit of code, it was pulled from an answer to a post from here, so I'm not to blame for that :-)

Comment: You may also want to check out `ImageFileApply`, `ImageFileFilter`, and `ImageFileScan` for out-of-core image processing if you run into memory problems.

Comment: @bills It comes up with a whole bunch of error messages if I try to use ImageSubtract on a table, most relating to the table not being an image. flinty's answer seems to have solved this though!